# Media queries for all devices

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Is there a simpler way for making my website look good on different mobile devices other than setting a different media query for all devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use media queries to make website responsive but you have to adjust for various screens like for ipad

```
/* ----------- iPad mini ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* ----------- iPad 1 and 2 ----------- */
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* ----------- iPad 3 and 4 ----------- */
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}
```

Similarly you can looks for other devices like laptops , tablets, mini phones etc. Here is an article which has given sizes of all screens for media screens https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ . There is no point in rewriting that all again here.

Apart from media queries you can use frameworks like bootstrap which reduces headache of using media queries instead you can just use their classes which have predefined css.

Comment: `device-width` and `device-height` have been depreciated. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries]

Comment: @IgnatOspadov your link doesn't work

Comment: oops the formatting for the link has a typo. Same link without the formatting typo: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Answer (score 2):

Can you just do it by width?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    // CSS Here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You normally use few media queries: 1200, 992, 768 and maybe 480. That's not that many if you want your website to be fully responsive. Alternatively, you can learn and use Bootstrap which helps a lot with responsiveness.